# invalid literal for float():

Tags: python, knn

I'm new with python. So maybe there is something really basic here I'm missing, but I can't figure it out...For my work I'm trying to read a txt file and apply KNN on it.

The File content is as follow and it has three columns with the third one as the class, the separator is a space.

```
0.85    17.45   2
0.75    15.6    2
3.3     15.45   2
5.25    14.2    2
4.9     15.65   2
5.35    15.85   2
5.1     17.9    2
4.6     18.25   2
4.05    18.75   2
3.4     19.7    2
2.9     21.15   2
3.1     21.85   2
3.9     21.85   2
4.4     20.05   2
7.2     14.5    2
7.65    16.5    2
7.1     18.65   2
7.05    19.9    2
5.85    20.55   2
5.5     21.8    2
6.55    21.8    2
6.05    22.3    2
5.2     23.4    2
4.55    23.9    2
5.1     24.4    2
8.1     26.35   2
10.15   27.7    2
9.75    25.5    2
9.2     21.1    2
11.2    22.8    2
12.6    23.1    2
13.25   23.5    2
11.65   26.85   2
12.45   27.55   2
13.3    27.85   2
13.7    27.75   2
14.15   26.9    2
14.05   26.55   2
15.15   24.2    2
15.2    24.75   2
12.2    20.9    2
12.15   21.45   2
12.75   22.05   2
13.15   21.85   2
13.75   22  2
13.95   22.7    2
14.4    22.65   2
14.2    22.15   2
14.1    21.75   2
14.05   21.4    2
17.2    24.8    2
17.7    24.85   2
17.55   25.2    2
17      26.85   2
16.55   27.1    2
19.15   25.35   2
18.8    24.7    2
21.4    25.85   2
15.8    21.35   2
16.6    21.15   2
17.45   20.75   2
18      20.95   2
18.25   20.2    2
18      22.3    2
18.6    22.25   2
19.2    21.95   2
19.45   22.1    2
20.1    21.6    2
20.1    20.9    2
19.9    20.35   2
19.45   19.05   2
19.25   18.7    2
21.3    22.3    2
22.9    23.65   2
23.15   24.1    2
24.25   22.85   2
22.05   20.25   2
20.95   18.25   2
21.65   17.25   2
21.55   16.7    2
21.6    16.3    2
21.5    15.5    2
22.4    16.5    2
22.25   18.1    2
23.15   19.05   2
23.5    19.8    2
23.75   20.2    2
25.15   19.8    2
25.5    19.45   2
23      18      2
23.95   17.75   2
25.9    17.55   2
27.65   15.65   2
23.1    14.6    2
23.5    15.2    2
24.05   14.9    2
24.5    14.7    2
14.15   17.35   1
14.3    16.8    1
14.3    15.75   1
14.75   15.1    1
15.35   15.5    1
15.95   16.45   1
16.5    17.05   1
17.35   17.05   1
17.15   16.3    1
16.65   16.1    1
16.5    15.15   1
16.25   14.95   1
16      14.25   1
15.9    13.2    1
15.15   12.05   1
15.2    11.7    1
17      15.65   1
16.9    15.35   1
17.35   15.45   1
17.15   15.1    1
17.3    14.9    1
17.7    15      1
17      14.6    1
16.85   14.3    1
16.6    14.05   1
17.1    14      1
17.45   14.15   1
17.8    14.2    1
17.6    13.85   1
17.2    13.5    1
17.25   13.15   1
17.1    12.75   1
16.95   12.35   1
16.5    12.2    1
16.25   12.5    1
16.05   11.9    1
16.65   10.9    1
16.7    11.4    1
16.95   11.25   1
17.3    11.2    1
18.05   11.9    1
18.6    12.5    1
18.9    12.05   1
18.7    11.25   1
17.95   10.9    1
18.4    10.05   1
17.45   10.4    1
17.6    10.15   1
17.7    9.85    1
17.3    9.7     1
16.95   9.7     1
16.75   9.65    1
19.8    9.95    1
19.1    9.55    1
17.5    8.3     1
17.55   8.1     1
17.85   7.55    1
18.2    8.35    1
19.3    9.1     1
19.4    8.85    1
19.05   8.85    1
18.9    8.5     1
18.6    7.85    1
18.7    7.65    1
19.35   8.2     1
19.95   8.3     1
20      8.9     1
20.3    8.9     1
20.55   8.8     1
18.35   6.95    1
18.65   6.9     1
19.3    7       1
19.1    6.85    1
19.15   6.65    1
21.2    8.8     1
21.4    8.8     1
21.1    8       1
20.4    7       1
20.5    6.35    1
20.1    6.05    1
20.45   5.15    1
20.95   5.55    1
20.95   6.2     1
20.9    6.6     1
21.05   7       1
21.85   8.5     1
21.9    8.2     1
22.3    7.7     1
21.85   6.65    1
21.3    5.05    1
22.6    6.7     1
22.5    6.15    1
23.65   7.2     1
24.1    7       1
21.95   4.8     1
22.15   5.05    1
22.45   5.3     1
22.45   4.9     1
22.7    5.5     1
23      5.6     1
23.2    5.3     1
23.45   5.95    1
23.75   5.95    1
24.45   6.15    1
24.6    6.45    1
25.2    6.55    1
26.05   6.4     1
25.3    5.75    1
24.35   5.35    1
23.3    4.9     1
22.95   4.75    1
22.4    4.55    1
22.8    4.1     1
22.9    4       1
23.25   3.85    1
23.45   3.6     1
23.55   4.2     1
23.8    3.65    1
23.8    4.75    1
24.2    4       1
24.55   4       1
24.7    3.85    1
24.7    4.3     1
24.9    4.75    1
26.4    5.7     1
27.15   5.95    1
27.3    5.45    1
27.5    5.45    1
27.55   5.1     1
26.85   4.95    1
26.6    4.9     1
26.85   4.4     1
26.2    4.4     1
26      4.25    1
25.15   4.1     1
25.6    3.9     1
25.85   3.6     1
24.95   3.35    1
25.1    3.25    1
25.45   3.15    1
26.85   2.95    1
27.15   3.15    1
27.2    3       1
27.95   3.25    1
27.95   3.5     1
28.8    4.05    1
28.8    4.7     1
28.75   5.45    1
28.6    5.75    1
29.25   6.3     1
30      6.55    1
30.6    3.4     1
30.05   3.45    1
29.75   3.45    1
29.2    4       1
29.45   4.05    1
29.05   4.55    1
29.4    4.85    1
29.5    4.7     1
29.9    4.45    1
30.75   4.45    1
30.4    4.05    1
30.8    3.95    1
31.05   3.95    1
30.9    5.2     1
30.65   5.85    1
30.7    6.15    1
31.5    6.25    1
31.65   6.55    1
32      7       1
32.5    7.95    1
33.35   7.45    1
32.6    6.95    1
32.65   6.6     1
32.55   6.35    1
32.35   6.1     1
32.55   5.8     1
32.2    5.05    1
32.35   4.25    1
32.9    4.15    1
32.7    4.6     1
32.75   4.85    1
34.1    4.6     1
34.1    5       1
33.6    5.25    1
33.35   5.65    1
33.75   5.95    1
33.4    6.2     1
34.45   5.8     1
34.65   5.65    1
34.65   6.25    1
35.25   6.25    1
34.35   6.8     1
34.1    7.15    1
34.45   7.3     1
34.7    7.2     1
34.85   7       1
34.35   7.75    1
34.55   7.85    1
35.05   8       1
35.5    8.05    1
35.8    7.1     1
36.6    6.7     1
36.75   7.25    1
36.5    7.4     1
35.95   7.9     1
36.1    8.1     1
36.15   8.4     1
37.6    7.35    1
37.9    7.65    1
29.15   4.4     1
34.9    9       1
35.3    9.4     1
35.9    9.35    1
36      9.65    1
35.75   10      1
36.7    9.15    1
36.6    9.8     1
36.9    9.75    1
37.25   10.15   1
36.4    10.15   1
36.3    10.7    1
36.75   10.85   1
38.15   9.7     1
38.4    9.45    1
38.35   10.5    1
37.7    10.8    1
37.45   11.15   1
37.35   11.4    1
37      11.75   1
36.8    12.2    1
37.15   12.55   1
37.25   12.15   1
37.65   11.95   1
37.95   11.85   1
38.6    11.75   1
38.5    12.2    1
38      12.95   1
37.3    13      1
37.5    13.4    1
37.85   14.5    1
38.3    14.6    1
38.05   14.45   1
38.35   14.35   1
38.5    14.25   1
39.3    14.2    1
39      13.2    1
38.95   12.9    1
39.2    12.35   1
39.5    11.8    1
39.55   12.3    1
39.75   12.75   1
40.2    12.8    1
40.4    12.05   1
40.45   12.5    1
40.55   13.15   1
40.45   14.5    1
40.2    14.8    1
40.65   14.9    1
40.6    15.25   1
41.3    15.3    1
40.95   15.7    1
41.25   16.8    1
40.95   17.05   1
40.7    16.45   1
40.45   16.3    1
39.9    16.2    1
39.65   16.2    1
39.25   15.5    1
38.85   15.5    1
38.3    16.5    1
38.75   16.85   1
39      16.6    1
38.25   17.35   1
39.5    16.95   1
39.9    17.05   1
```

My Code:

```
import csv
import random
import math
import operator

def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=[] , testSet=[]):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        for x in range(len(dataset)-1):
            for y in range(3):
                dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
            if random.random() < split:
                trainingSet.append(dataset[x])
            else:
                testSet.append(dataset[x])


def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
    distance = 0
    for x in range(length):
        distance += pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)

def getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k):
    distances = []
    length = len(testInstance)-1
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
        distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for x in range(k):
        neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
    return neighbors

def getResponse(neighbors):
    classVotes = {}
    for x in range(len(neighbors)):
        response = neighbors[x][-1]
        if response in classVotes:
            classVotes[response] += 1
        else:
            classVotes[response] = 1
    sortedVotes = sorted(classVotes.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedVotes[0][0]

def getAccuracy(testSet, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[x][-1] == predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct/float(len(testSet))) * 100.0

def main():
    # prepare data
    trainingSet=[]
    testSet=[]
    split = 0.67
    loadDataset('Jain.txt', split, trainingSet, testSet)
    print 'Train set: ' + repr(len(trainingSet))
    print 'Test set: ' + repr(len(testSet))
    # generate predictions
    predictions=[]
    k = 3
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[x], k)
        result = getResponse(neighbors)
        predictions.append(result)
        print('> predicted=' + repr(result) + ', actual=' + repr(testSet[x][-1]))
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
    print('Accuracy: ' + repr(accuracy) + '%')
main()
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to read it as a CSV (comma-separated values). Seems like your data is more suited to just being read as a text file.

Comment: @StephenCowley The csv module supports being used with any separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

You have to [tell csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) [what separator to use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) - else it will use the default excel ',' separator. Note that in the example you posted, the separator might actually NOT be "a space", but either a tab (`"\t"` in python) or just a random number of spaces - in which case it's not a csv-like format and you'll have to parse lines by yourself.

Also your code is far from pythonic. First thing first: python's 'for' loop are really "for each" kind of loops, ie they directly yields values from the object you iterate on. The proper way to iterate on a list is:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
for item in lst:
    print(item)
```

so no need for `range()` and indexed access here. Note that if you want to have the index too, you can use `enumerate(sequence)`, which will yield `(index, item)` pairs, ie:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    print("item at {} is {}".format(index, item))
```

So your loadDataset() function could be rewritten as:

```
def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=None , testSet=None):
    # fix the mutable default argument gotcha
    # cf https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments
    if trainingSet is None:
        trainingSet = []
    if testSet is None:
        testSet = []

with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")

    for row in reader:
        row = tuple(float(x) for x in row)
        if random.random() < split:
            trainingSet.append(row)
        else:
            testSet.append(row)

# so the caller can get the values back
return trainingSet, testSet
```

Note that if any value in your file is not a proper representation of a float, you'll still get a `ValueError` in `row = tuple(float(x) for x in row)`. The solution here is to catch the error and handle it one way or another - either by reraising it with additionnal debugging info (which value is wrong and which line of the file it belongs to) or by logging the error and ignoring this row or however it makes sense in the context of your app / lib:

```
    for row in reader:
        try:
            row = tuple(float(x) for x in row)
        except ValueError as e:
            # here we choose to just log the error 
            # and ignore the row, but you may want
            # to do otherwise, your choice... 
            print("wrong value in line {}: {}".format(reader.line_num, row))
            continue

        if random.random() < split:
            trainingSet.append(row)
        else:
            testSet.append(row)
```

Also, if you want to iterate over two lists in parallel (get 'list1[x], list2[x]' pairs), [you can use `zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
lst1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
lst2 = ["x", "y", "z"]

for pair in zip(lst1, lst2):
    print(pair)
```

and there are functions to `sum()` values from an iterable, ie:

lst = [1, 2, 3]
  print(sum(lst))

so your `euclideanDistance` function can be rewritten as:

```
def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
    pairs = zip(instance1[:length], instance2[:length])
    return math.sqrt(sum(pow(x - y) for x, y in pairs))
```

etc etc...

Comment: I am still having an error in this line
row = tuple(float[x] for x in row)
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: my bad! should have been `float(x)` of course (typo fixed in the answer)

Comment: Oh and yes: you may still have `ValueError` if there are any data in your file that is not a proper representation of a `float` - in which case you'll have to handle the issue one way or another. I edited my post to add an example of error handling.

Comment: yeah there was this error, the first seven lines were string as an introduction to the file, so i skipped reading the first 7 lines